# Can I install a second Hadoop with CDH if I already installed Hadoop with Ambari? On the same machines

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, ambari

Can I have a second Hadoop cluster with CDH if I already have a Hadoop cluster installed with Ambari on the same three machines?
If yes, how can I migrate data on the original cluster to the new cluster?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but it is not a straightforward task. You'll have port clashes between HDP and CDH services. So, you'll have to choose different ports for your CDH cluster. Another pain point to be taken care of - both clusters will want to use /etc/hadoop, /etc/hive,... for storing configuration files. So, one of the cluster should be configured to use a different location.

Regarding data migration, use distcp.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to accomplish is called "Ambari Takeover" or "Cluster takeover". See [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6703/ambari-server-installation-after-cluster-setup.html) discussion for more information.

Some important notes from here:
This would be quite challenging and complex as you will have to perform fresh Ambari setup and complete Ambari Takeover of existing HDP cluster in absence of database backup. You have three options:

1. If cluster is not production and there is feasibility of cleaning up the  cluster, then I would recommend to clean up the cluster and setup fresh  one using Ambari. This would save you a lot of time. Even if there is  some data, just weigh in time and effort trade off for backing up data  and doing fresh install vs performing Ambari Takeover as explained at  high level in next two options.
2. Cluster Takeover using Ambari APIs Setup Ambari Server and Ambari database as earlier on new machine.Update Ambari-Agents to point to Ambari-server host. Use Ambari APIs to perform cluster takeover i.e. add cluster, add hosts, register services and components, register host components. Refer below for Ambari APIs.
   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/API+usage+scenarios%2C+troubleshooting%2C+and+other+FAQs
3. Third option would be to perform a dummy cluster install using Ambari and then updating configs in Ambari.

Note:
 Ensure that you take database, install directories and config backups at regular frequency going forward and move those to another backup server or HDFS to avoid further issues due to hardware failures. 
Note: Ensure that you take database, install directories and config backups at regular frequency going forward and move those to another backup server or HDFS to avoid further issues due to hardware failures.